# How to detect `delete` and `.` when user press the keyboard on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, keyboard

When I press `.` it fires the three events, `keydown`, `keypress` and `keyup`.

```
keydown
  which: 190 == ¾
  keyCode: 190 == ¾

keypress
  which: 46 == .
  keyCode: 46 == .

keyup
  which: 190 == ¾
  keyCode: 190 == ¾
```

When I press `delete` it fires **two** events, `keydown` and `keyup`.

```
keydown
  which: 46 == .
  keyCode: 46 == .

keyup
  which: 46 == .
  keyCode: 46 == .
```

I want to press `.` and be able to get the corresponding character (`46 == .`). But on `keydown` and `keyup` I get `190` which is `¾`. On the `keypress` I get the correct value, but this event is not fired when I press `delete`.

When I press `delete` I get the code `46` on `keydown` and `keyup`. But the code `46` is a `.` and not `delete`.

How can I make an event to capture both keys and tell the difference, if it was a `.` pressed or `delete` key?

Page to test: http://jsfiddle.net/Eg9F3/

Comment: Can you illustrate by a jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @Christophe http://jsfiddle.net/Eg9F3/

Comment: Well, `delete` doesn't correspond to a character. In the olden days it would map to a low character value, but that's not really how it works now. So you have _two_ scenarios here and need to distinguish them. What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've forced the same behavior as Firefox, [example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eg9F3/3/)

```
$("textarea").keydown(function(e) {
    // if the key pressed was found on the list of specialChars
    if (specialChars[e.keyCode])
    {
        // triggers the fake event
        $("textarea").trigger("chromekeypress", e);

        // temporary avoid keypress from firing
        $("textarea").unbind("keypress");
        setTimeout(function(){ $("textarea").bind("keypress", handleKey); },10);
    }
});

$("textarea").keypress(handleKey); // main event

$("textarea").bind("chromekeypress", chromeKeyPress); // chrome workaround

function chromeKeyPress(i,e){
    e.type="chromekeypress";
    e.which = 0; // copy Firefox behavior, which == 0 means a special key pressed
    handleKey(e); // fires the main event
}
function handleKey(e) {

    // which is going to be 0 if it is a special key
    // and keycode will have the code of the special key
    // or
    // which will have the value of the key

    $("#r").html($("#r").html() + "\n" +
        e.type + "\n" +
        "  which: " + e.which + " == " + String.fromCharCode(e.which) + "\n" +
        "  keyCode: " + e.keyCode + " == " + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) + "\n" +
     "");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution would be to map the keys you want ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AqTLA/)), then use `e.which` to cross-reference what key was pressed. There is a [good reference](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) of cross-browser `keyCode` values, which work in this case because jQuery normalizes the `e.which` value.

```
var keys = {
  46  : 'del',
  190 : '.'
};

$("textarea").bind('keyup', function(e){
  $('#r').append( 'keyup (' + e.which + '): ' + (keys[e.which] || String.fromCharCode(e.which)) );
});
```

This is similar to the method that [jQuery UI](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.core.js) uses - see the keycodes cross-reference at the top of the file? And it is also the method I use in the [keycaster](http://mottie.github.com/Keycaster/) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

In fact it's strange but it is logic.

The function String.fromCharCode is working with real char code, not with KB actions (left, delete...)

Why don't filter by keyCode simply ?

Answer (score 0):

The value of "which" in a "keypress" handler does not have the same meaning as that of "which" in a "keydown" or "keyup" handler.  In those, it's the *keycode* for the key on the keyboard, and *not* a character ordinal. In "keypress" it is the character, but you don't get a "keypress" for `Del` (as you've noticed).

Thus, that's a different 46 in the "keypress" handler (for ".") than in the "keydown" and "keyup" events for `Del`.

You probably should use either "keydown" or "keyup" and check for the keycode.