# Same code to detect DEL key in textarea does not run in my computer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect when user presses `Delete` key and I found the tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724895/how-to-detect-delete-and-when-user-press-the-keyboard-on-chrome)

The code works great in `jsfiddle.net`, this is the link- http://jsfiddle.net.
I copied the same code to my computer, and then I tested it but it didn't work up to the mark.

I am posting my code here:

```
<html>

<script src="./jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 


<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var specialChars = {
            27: "esc", 9: "tab", 32: "space", 13: "return", 8: "backspace", 145: "scroll", 20: "capslock", 144: "numlock",
            19: "pause", 45: "insert", 36: "home", 46: "del", 35: "end", 33: "pageup", 34: "pagedown",
            37: "left", 38: "up", 39: "right", 40: "down", 109: "-",
            112: "f1", 113: "f2", 114: "f3", 115: "f4", 116: "f5", 117: "f6",
            118: "f7", 119: "f8", 120: "f9", 121: "f10", 122: "f11", 123: "f12", 191: "/"
        };

function chromeKeyPress(i,e){
    e.type="chromekeypress";
    e.which = 0;
    handleKey(e);
}
function handleKey(e) {
    $("#r").html($("#r").html() + "\n" +
        e.type + "\n" +
        "  which: " + e.which + " == " + String.fromCharCode(e.which) + "\n" +
        "  keyCode: " + e.keyCode + " == " + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) + "\n" +
     "");
}

$("textarea").keydown(function(e) {
    if (specialChars[e.keyCode])
    {
        $("textarea").trigger("chromekeypress", e);

        $("textarea").unbind("keypress");
        setTimeout(function(){ $("textarea").bind("keypress", handleKey); },10);
    }
});
$("textarea").keypress(handleKey);
$("textarea").bind("chromekeypress", chromeKeyPress);

</script>


<textarea></textarea>

<pre id="r"></pre>


</body>
</html>
```

I linked the `jquery`, `jquery-1.10.2.min.js`.
what is wrong in my code for the `javascript`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your code inside DOM ready handler `$(document).ready(function() {....});` or shorter form `$(function) {...});` to make sure all of your DOM elements has been loaded properly before executing your jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    // Your jQuery code here
});
```

Your code works on `jsFiddle` because the above task has been done automatically when you've included jQuery from `jsFiddle`

Answer (score 0):

put your code inside ready event

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```